# how to switch tab programmatically if tab bar controller is inside another ui controller? -Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

hi I am new to ios development particularly in swift. Basically I just need to switch tab, I have tried `tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1` but it seem not to switch tab.

[image]

the image above is my story board, the initial set up is I have splitview controller the initial view that is on master is `tableViewController` which is `A` and **when tapped on the accessory** of cell the detail which is `detail of A` appear on detail of splitview and when **tapped on row itself**
the `Tab Bar Controller` replace the master

then I have four tabs in my tabBarController `Tab B`, `Tab C`, `Tab D`, and `Tab E` which is just a list when tapped it shows its respective view controller as detail of splitview then in my `tab E` I have 3 buttons each button designed to function to switch tab

**note: the tabs and details are embedded in navigation controller**

I'm a bit confuse on how and what is the standards for this.
Could anyone help me any comment, suggestion would do.

Answer (score 9):

The reason for

```
 tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```

is not working, is that tabBarController is nil.

In order to get the right tabBarController, you will have to get it from the root of window object.
Something like this,

```
var tabBarController: UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
```

Since, you might have to find right tabBarController in your navigation stack, you will have to traverse stack as well.
From the storyboard above, I believe you are loading tabbarController from a Tableview didSelect, so you will have to get tabBarController there and select tabbar index there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: my rootviewcontroller is the tableview A so i need to go there first the switch tab?

Comment: Yes correct, when you add tabbarcontroller to rootviewcontroller, you need switch tab. This tabbarcontroller is launched from tableview A

Comment: im a bit loss, i need to go to root controller (tableview A) first then initiate tapped to one of its cell so tabbar shows, then switch tab? I'm sorry i don't have idea what should i do.

Comment: I believe you are launching tabbar with selected index as per user's selection of tableview row, right?

Comment: One more thing, tabbarcontroller should be added to window rootviewcontroller when you present it, not as subview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77686/discussion-between-meet-and-caffeine-shots).

Answer (score 5):

In the identity inspector of the tab bar controller, I added a name to the storyboard ID "tabBarController". Within my action I add instantiate the view controller and cast UITabbarController. You'll be able to switch to the tab bar you selected. Hope this helps

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let vc: UITabBarController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController") as! UITabBarController
    vc.selectedIndex = 0  
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add in your AppDelegate.swift:   `var tabBarController: UITabBarController?`

and then you can put in another Controller  `self.tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 0`

worked for me